# Calculating the area of oyster drone imagery

Tags: qgis, raster, area

I'm working on analyzing the area of an oyster reef and its development over the past years. The shown ortophoto is already loaded in QGIS. The unit of this file is degrees. That's where my main problem lies. For my work, I need to have the area of **just** the oysters in square meters. When I used the SCP classification tool, it showed me an area in the unit degrees^2. Is there a way or a factor to transform degrees^2 to m^2? Or do I have to use another tool to get my area in m^2? What's the best way to find out the area?

The targeted area can be just the pure oyster area or the whole oyster area not regarding the empty spaces in the inside of the reef. Both ways work!

[image: oyster field]

Comment: Transform your image to a m-based CRS, most likely the local UTM-zone, then run the classification. Though this will slightly falsify your data. You could transform after classification, if the tool gives you polygons.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How can i transform my image toa CRS? Do you have guide for that?

Comment: CRS-transformation is one of the most basic things when it comes to using GIS. I suggest you get started with the QGIS tutorial.